# Is it enought to add mysql.h in my project or need other libraries too to work

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mysql-connector

I want to create a database which stores my data in the form of numbers and than show me the output on the interface for that i am configuring mysql serve 5.5 with visual studio 2010 c++ , i configure it using [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html) but my mode was debug and for additional include directories and additional libraries directories i select all configuration (active and debug) after that i add the below libraries

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
```

From above libraries #include  didn't show any error but all below didn't include , its my first time to work with mysql so just adding `mysql.h` is enough for my work or do it need to add the below libraries too .

I already installed MySQLconnector C 6.1 , MySQLconnector C++ 1.13 , MySqlConnector Net 6.5.7

`Error`

`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql_connection.h': No such file or directory`

Edit :

It showing error on no such file or directory on

```
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
```

As i follow the following steps in debug mode

ProjectName -> Properties -> VC++ Directories -> include directories

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include
```

than C/C++ -> Additional include directories

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include
```

than Linker -> Genral -> Additional Libraries Directories

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib
```

Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies

```
mysqlcppconn-static.lib
libmysql.lib
```

Comment: If you did the linker step it _should_ be okay

Comment: My Problem is solved , actually i was not linking to conn libraries of conector c++

Comment: you should mark it as solved then.

Answer (score 3):

The header file only provides declarations for functions and maybe some macros.

You will also need to link with libraries.  Search the web for "Visual Studio 2010 MySql Connector".

You may need to download the source for the connector and database and rebuild them to match your project.  I had to do this for VS 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit platform, but not with VS 2008, Vista, 32-bit platform.

Comment: You mean i need to change the version of connectors ? which i already installed

Comment: and for my work do i need to add all other libraries other than `mysql.h` because i just need to input the data and displaying the output

Comment: For example, if you want to use Unicode and have the Run-time library as using DLL, you will need to download the source of MySQL Connector C++, change the settings to use Unicode and rebuild.  This has nothing to do with version numbers.

Comment: In order to access the database, you need to link with the Connector libraries.  The connector requires the MySQL interface library.  So, yes, to get data out of the database, you will need to link with all the libraries.  Read the MySQL Connector documentation.

Comment: There is no option for me of `opt` in `lib` which they suggest for linking like `lib/opt` i have option of debug and plugin along with 2 libraries and 1 dll instead i have this option in lib of `MySQLconnector1.1.3`

Comment: @Ahmad: I do not understand your issue.  Did you make a custom build of the connector?  Are your library search directories pointed in the {new} locations?

Comment: My Problem is solved , actually i was not linking to conn libraries of conector c++ , Thanks for help